# Django REST Framework router prepending period on url reverse

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet registered in a router

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

So i try to reverse the url with a primary key

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
url_with_args = reverse('user-list', args=[user.pk])
url_with_kwargs = reverse('user-list', kwargs={'format':user.pk})
```

but the value of the urls is

```
url_with_args == '/api/users/.1'
url_with_kwargs == '/api/users/.1'
```

why is there a period in the primary key value?

I have also tried the same process with

```
rest_framework.reverse.reverse
```

but the values returned values are:

```
'/api/users/.1'
```

Comment: @KevinBrown yes it worked, i understand my mistake, i was trying to reverse a list when the detail was needed. Hhank for your look in the detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that you were using `user-list` instead of `user-detail` for the named URL. `user-list` is meant to go to the list view `/api/resource` while `user-detail` is meant to go to the detail view `/api/resource/1`.

The reason why `user-list` was giving you `/api/users/.1` is because the regex that it is matching is `/api/users/.(?<format>)` where `format` is the optional string that can be things like `xml` or `json` and control what renderer is used`.

The regex for `user-detail` is `/api/users/(?<pk>)` where `pk` is a non-optional parameter used for matching the primary key when retrieving the object.